# Translation request cursive

Tags: translation

An administrator should delete this post as I don't see how it is useful to the community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a native Hebrew speaker. It says: "I love (a girl is loving) you, my dear Mika" (Mika is a name).  In Hebrew: "אני אוהבת אותך מיקה שלי" (technically it says I love you my Mika (but saying my Mika in English in this context doesn't make sense, in Hebrew it's like saying my dear Mika in English)).

Comment: Is the sentence gender specific ? A man would write it differently ?

Comment: @mwa1 Yes, if it was a man saying he love Mika it will be: "אני אוהב אותך מיקה שלי".